# What tfs 2010 object references are available for Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.tbl_ReleaseNoteDetails

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

We have a Team Project Collection Source Control Setting for Check-in Notes that requires each check-in to capture a "Tracking Number". This number is external to TFS. I need to search for all the changesets that have a specific Tracking number.

The resulting changeset list tells me what to GetLatest on, for our monthly deployment.

--  We don't use Work Items

This .SQL gives me the list I'm looking for.  I want to access this in code from Visual Studio.

```
SELECT ReleaseNoteId, FieldName, BaseValue
from Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.tbl_ReleaseNoteDetails
  where ReleaseNoteId in (SELECT ReleaseNoteId
FROM Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.tbl_ReleaseNote
  where DateCreated between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31')
    and FieldName = 'Tracker #'
    and BaseValue = '18570'
```

What object references are available for Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.tbl_ReleaseNoteDetails?

Comment: **Required note**: Querying the ProjectCollection database directly is completely unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 1to1 object reference in the TFS API, because you usually don't work on the structure like the database looks like.

What I understand from your description, you have the information you need in the changesets. In that case you could use the `VersionControlServer` to get the changesets and get the information from there.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsConnection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://TFS:8080/TFS/DefaultCollection"));
VersionControlServer sourceControl = (VersionControlServer)tfsConnection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
IEnumerable changesets = sourceControl.QueryHistory(ServerPath, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, new DateVersionSpec (new DateTime(2013,1,1)), new DateVersionSpec (new DateTime(2013,1,31)), Int32.MaxValue, true, false);
foreach (Changeset change in changesets)
{
  // check where the information is stored in the changeset, may change.Changes
}
```

Just an idea to get in the right direction.

Comment: This code is "close" to what I want. It will allow my to search by Comment.  I need to search by NOTE.                 IEnumerable changesets = this.versionControlServer.QueryHistory(
                    sc.SearchFile,
                    VersionSpec.Latest,
                    0,
                    RecursionType.Full,
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sc.SearchUser) ? null : sc.SearchUser,
                    sc.FromDateVersion,
                    sc.ToDateVersion,
                    Int32.MaxValue,
                    true,
                    false);

Comment: The `Changeset` object also has a property `CheckinNote` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.checkinnote(v=vs.100).aspx), that could be yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy querying and searching, you're better off creating a new work item field and associate the work item during checkin. Work items have complete querying capabilities in the UI and are even transported to the Reporting warehouse.

You could retrieve the history for a specific folder, date range etc using a `QueryHistoryParameters` object and then iterate over the `CheckinNotes` to filter:

```
  var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
      new Uri("http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
  var versionControlServer = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

  var query = new QueryHistoryParameters("$/Scrum/**", RecursionType.Full);
  var changesets = server.QueryHistory(query);

  changesets.Where(cs => cs.CheckinNotes.Any(note => note.PropertyName == "Tracker #" 
       && note.Value == "18570"))
```

This is not going to be terribly fast. To get a quick solution, use work item association.